# Problems with NSNumber

Tags: c++, foundation, theos

Hey guys i'm building a tweak for instagram i'm adding a sub preference called instatroll similar to trolltwitter to change the number of followers to any number the user sets (using PSEditTextCell) here is my code so far

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
static NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]     initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.idevicelover.InstaEnhancer.plist"];


NSNumber *chosenNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:999];
int number = chosenNumber;
static BOOL followerson = NO;


%hook IGUser -(void)setFollowerCount:(NSNumber*)fp8{
followerson = [[plist objectForKey:@"followerson"]boolValue];
if(followerson){

%orig(number);
}
else{
%orig;
}
}



%end


%ctor
{

NSDictionary *InstaEnhancer = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var    /mobile    /Library/Preferences/com.idevicelover.InstaEnhancer.plist"];
 if ([InstaEnhancer objectForKey:@"numberoffollowers"]) number = [[InstaEnhancer objectForKey:@"numberoffollowers"] intValue];
[InstaEnhancer release];

}
```

i'm getting this error when compiling :"assigning to NSNumber * from incompatible type "int"

Comment: I don't know what is going on in your code... for 1 it is objective-c or maybe objective-c++ but certainly not c++ and what is `%end` this isn't lex right?

Comment: This is almost Objective-C, but some of the things look odd for Objective-C.  Normally, we'd see `@end` sure, but I have no idea what `%hook`, `%orig`, or `%ctor` are... but since the real problem is with `NSNumber`, the [tag:foundation] tag is appropriate since `NSNumber` is definitely out of that no matter the language you're using.

Comment: %hook, %orig, %end, %ctor and more are directives for [logos](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos), it's a preprocessor that simplifies tweak making. It's a component of Theos, which is why the tag is there (not Theos as in an OS, but a build environment).

Comment: many didn't understand the language this is logos with objective C coded using theos (developed by dustin howett) to make substrate tweaks

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumber` is an object.  In order to use it as a primitive data type such as an `int`, you have to pull that type of value out of it with the appropriate method:

```
NSNumber *chosenNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:999];
int number = [chosenNumber intValue];
```

Also, later on, here:

```
number = [[InstaEnhancer objectForKey:@"numberoffollowers"] intValue];
```

If at this point `number` is an `int` (I have no clue as this syntax isn't C++ or Objective-C) then this should be fine.  But if `number` is of type `NSNumber *`, then you need to drop the call to `intValue`:

```
number = [InstaEnhancer objectForKey:@"numberoffollowers"];
```

Comment: Now Im getting cannot initialize a parameter of type nsnumber * with type rvalue "int " :(

Comment: This is logos i'm coding a substrate tweak using theos any luck with my error ?

Comment: @user3551278, use a paste service to post the output of `make clean all messages=yes`. That usually gives others more context with which to help you